# WP UI fails to install plugin even when plugins directory set to 777

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress server is managed manually through the terminal, no cPanel and such. I'm trying to install plugins through the Wordpress plugin "add new" UI button. I get `Installation failed: Could not create directory.` I did `chown -R www-data:www-data {wordpress location}` and `chmod -R 755 {wordpress location}` but I still get the same issue. Even 777 gives me the same error. I did verify that the folder is owned by `www-data:www-data`. The `www-data` group contains the `www-data` user and the `wpman` user, which is the user defined in `wp-config.php` as the `FTP_USER`. I am at my wit's end - what could possibly be the issue?

When I turn on debugging, I get this massive error message:

`Installation failed: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Ad_Rotator_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use __construct() instead. Backtrace from noticeIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 3893]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 3893] calling trigger_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php [line 200] calling _deprecated_constructor() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotator/adrotator.php [line 32] calling WP_Widget() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php [line 106] calling Ad_Rotator_Widget() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/widgets.php [line 113] calling register() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotator/adrotator.php [line 79] calling register_widget() [line ?] calling register_Ad_Rotator_Widget() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 298] calling call_user_func_array() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 453] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-settings.php [line 449] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-config.php [line 94] calling require_once() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-load.php [line 37] calling require_once() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 22] calling require_once() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php [line 1280]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php [line 1280] calling setcookie() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php [line 4692] calling setcookie() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php [line 4617] calling setCookie() [line ?] calling initAction() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 298] calling call_user_func_array() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 453] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-settings.php [line 449] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-config.php [line 94] calling require_once() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-load.php [line 37] calling require_once() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 22] calling require_once() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/http.php [line 491]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/http.php [line 491] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 25] calling send_origin_headers() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/http.php [line 492]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/http.php [line 492] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 25] calling send_origin_headers() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 37]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 37] calling header() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 38]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 38] calling header() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 4915]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 4915] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 40] calling send_nosniff_header() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1144]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1144] calling header_remove() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 41] calling nocache_headers() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1157]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1157] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 41] calling nocache_headers() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1157]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 1157] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 41] calling nocache_headers() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 5020]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 5020] calling header() [line ?] calling send_frame_options_header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 296] calling call_user_func_array() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 453] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 44] calling do_action() Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/no-white-screen.php:140) Backtrace from warningIn /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 3157]: [line ?] calling process_error() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 3157] calling header() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/functions.php [line 3187] calling wp_send_json() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php [line 3642] calling wp_send_json_success() [line ?] calling wp_ajax_install_plugin() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 298] calling call_user_func_array() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 453] calling do_action() /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/mnt_www/mnt_www/html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [line 91] calling do_action() {"success":true,"data":{"install":"plugin","slug":"jetpack","pluginName":"Jetpack by WordPress.com","debug":["Downloading install package from https:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/plugin\/jetpack.4.9.zip&#8230;","Unpacking the package&#8230;","Installing the plugin&#8230;","Plugin installed successfully."],"activateUrl":"http:\/\/www.website.com\/wp-admin\/plugins.php?_wpnonce=04c27e2798&action=activate&plugin=jetpack\/jetpack.php"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error message we can see that you are trying install Ad Rotator plugin. It uses old object constructor method, which is deprecated from WordPress version 4.3.0.

It is not unusual. In WordPress repository we can see that this plugin wasn't updated for 2 years already.

You have to find another plugin for your needs.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the last line, I'm trying to install jetpack. I don't know where the other messages are coming from.

Comment: Do you have plugin Ad Rotator installed on your site?

Comment: I do. I deactivated it. Seems like I can install plugins now. Weird, why would that affect installation of other plugins?

Comment: Because installation of a complicated new plugin like Jet Pack can cause initialization of many internal structures, likes widgets in your case.